# How can I initiate a quiz by clicking on a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, undefined

I've build a quiz app. I want the user to be able to click a play button and the quiz start again from question one after the user has finished the first round. right now, if the user starts answering the question, after the last question the play button appears for the user to click and continue playing. the problem right now is when the click on play there is an error from line 40 saying cannot read undefined.

```
var questionElement = document.getElementById('questions');
    var answerElement = document.getElementById('answers');
    var scoreBoard = document.querySelector('#score-board');
    const playBtn = document.querySelector('#play-btn');
    const playScore = document.querySelector('#play-score');
    const state = {
    currentQuestionIndex: 0,
    score: 0
 };

var questions = [
{ question: " 1. javaScript is an....... language?",
    answers: [ "object-oriented", "object-based", "procedural", "none of the above"],
    correct: 1
    
},
{ question: " 2.which of the following keywords is used a define variable in javaScript",
    answers: [ "var", "let", "both A and B", "none of the above"],
    correct: 2

  
}, 
{
    question: "3. which of the following methods is used to HTML elements using javaScript",
    answers: ["getElementsById", "getElementByClassName", "both A and B", "none of the above"] ,
    correct: 2
    
}
];


function showQuestion(questionIndex){
    const question = questions[questionIndex];
    const qDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    
    questionElement.innerHTML = "";
    answerElement.innerHTML = "";

    p.textContent = question.question;
    qDiv.appendChild(p);
    questionElement.appendChild(qDiv);
    
    
    question.answers.forEach((answers, answerIndex) =>{
        const $input = document.createElement('input');
        const $label = document.createElement('label');
        $label.appendChild($input);
        
        $label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(answers));
        $input.name = `question${questionIndex}`;
        $input.type = 'radio';
        $input.value = answerIndex;
        answerElement.append($label);
    });
    
};


var nBtn = document.querySelector('.nbtn');
nBtn.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion);

const $answers = document.getElementById("answers");
$answers.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  const currentQuestion = questions[state.currentQuestionIndex];
  const selectedAnswerIndex = Number(event.target.value);
  const correctAnswerIndex = currentQuestion.correct;
  const isCorrect = selectedAnswerIndex === correctAnswerIndex;
  state.score += isCorrect ? 1 : 0;
});
showQuestion(0);

function nextQuestion() {
state.currentQuestionIndex += 1;
        if (state.currentQuestionIndex === questions.length) {
             removeLastQuestion();
             hidePlayBtn();
             //scorePage();
             showScores();
             showPlayBtn();
    } else{
        
        showQuestion(state.currentQuestionIndex)
    }   
};


function showScores() {
    if (state.currentQuestionIndex === questions.length) {
        scoreBoard.innerHTML = `${state.score}/${questions.length}`
    }   
}

function removeLastQuestion(){
         if (state.currentQuestionIndex > questions.length - 1) {
             questionElement.innerHTML = "";
             answerElement.innerHTML = "";
     }  
}

function scorePage() {
    if (state.currentQuestionIndex > questions.length -1) {
        window.location.href = 'index23.html';
     
    }

}

const score = document.querySelector('#play-score');
score.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
scoreBoard.innerText = `${state.score}/${questions.length}`;
        
});
const hidePlayBtn = function() {
nBtn.style.display = 'none';
playScore.style.display = 'none';

}


const init = function() {
    // showQuestion(0);

}

const showPlayBtn = function() {
    playBtn.style.display = 'block';
}

window.onload = function() {
    showQuestion(0);
    playBtn.style.display = 'none';
    playScore.style.display = 'none';
}

playBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    showQuestion(state.currentQuestionIndex);

    // nextQuestion();
    // showQuestion(state.currentQuestionIndex)
    // init();
    // nBtn.style.display = 'block';

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have set the `state` as a variable, not a const

And then in the `showPlayBtn` function, reset the `state.currentQuestionIndex` to 0

I hope this helps